# JavaScript Mutation observer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Mutation Observer. I use config:

```
config = { characterData: true, characterDataOldValue: true };
```

My html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test" contenteditable="true">Test<b>subtree</b>test</p>
```

Mutation observer is not working until I put subtree in the config:

```
config = { characterData: true, subtree: true, characterDataOldValue: true };
```

Can anybody explain why? I don't understand.

Comment: Can you please show us more of your code? What target element are you observing with `.observe()`?

Comment: Instead of using a mutation observer, consider using the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

Comment: target element id

Comment: Guys, I'm trying to use the Example from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

Well below is the code of mutation observer and it works properly. Can you show more of your code so one can find what exactly the problem is.
And for more information you must refer to this
[DOM MutationObserver – reacting to DOM changes without killing browser performance.](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

```js
const targetNode = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(targetNode);

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList,observer)=>{
  console.log("working");
});

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();
```

```html
<p id="test" contenteditable="true">Test</p>
```